# Help styling a view at runtime.

Tags: android

I've jumped around looking for a proper solution to this problem, but can't find one. The answer might be that it's impossible, but I'm going to try one more time, even though many similar questions have been asked.

I have a view (it happens to be a RatingBar, but it could be a button or a TextView or even an ImageView) that I want a custom style for. Depending on *something*, I want it to (for example) use Red Stars, or Blue Stars, or Orange Stars. I want to use this view in a list, with a custom list adapter, so that based on some attribute in the underlying list data, the item list view shows either the Red-Star RatingBar, or the Blue-Star RatingBar, or the OrangeStar RatingBar.

I've attempted building a style from code (choosing the right drawables that reflect the color stars I want), and then having the custom ListAdapter create a new RatingBar with the appropriate style (since a view's style can't be changed after the view is created), but when I do that the RatingBar never shows up. I'm not sure if this is expected, or if I have something else wrong.

It's like I want a selector for my image selector, or maybe another (custom?) attribute for the selector I already have.

If I create a CustomView, that extends RatingBar, that has an extra attribute, would an xml-defined Selector be able to access that attribute and use it to select a different image?

I'd like to figure this out, because the only alternative I can come up with is to not use a ListView with a ListAdapter, which basically results in me writing more custom code.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using themes? You can define a theme for the RatingBar in styles.xml. Within this RatingBar theme you can define a android:progressDrawable, which will refer to a drawable. Create multiple themes, that each point to a different drawable. Having these different themes, you will be able to programmatically set the RatingBar Widget android:style attribute to support these themes (red, blue, green) that you create.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that and see how it goes.

Comment: I don't think so. Themes apply to an entire Activity, rather than a single view. So I wouldn't be able to have 3 of my rating bars in one activity, all with different colors. I haven't entirely given up though.

Comment: Ah, I guess I misspoke. When I was referring to themes, I really just meant styles. You can define multiple styles that you can apply to different views.

Comment: That's what I tried. What I found is that a style can't be applied to a view after it's been created; You can supposedly build a style and apply it at runtime (you can't apply a style defined in xml at runtime), but when I tried it for a RatingBar it just didn't show up. It seems so straightforward, yet challenging at the same time.

Comment: Hmm, that is unfortunate. One option would be to define 3 different RatingBars in XML, and then control their visibility. In this way would not be styling at runtime. Unfortunately this is a waste of resources, and could slow things down bigtime in a ListView. That is really all I got, the only other suggestion I have is to try styling RatingBars programmatically in a test project so you can try to decompose the problem into smaller and smaller parts, then maybe you will figure out what is going wrong. Good luck!